# Is there a javascript server-side interpreter, like php?

Tags: javascript, server-side

For example, writting server-side things using javascript, instend of php.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160863/whats-a-good-minimal-server-side-javascript-framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Aptana Jaxer](http://jaxer.org) is very neat. You can even manipulate the DOM, and call server-side JS functions from the client.

Comment: Wikipedia says it is dead, how is that possible? It's so amazing.

Comment: I noticed that too, but it seems far from dead to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Aptana has stopped development on it. I think they have made an official announcement about it, too, but I'm not sure. To be honest, it didn't really catch much interest.

Comment: @musicfreak: I suppose. It's a shame though, it was a nice product - really had the potential to speed up web development.

Answer (score 6):

Check out node.js (http://nodejs.org/).
Server-side javascript with asynchronous stuff. Very neat.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but node.js's interpreter is simply google rebranded V8?.

Comment: No, not rebranded. It uses V8, and it says so. But it adds code to make it efficiently run server-side, file system APIs, network, low-level stuff. Check it out!

Answer (score 2):

There is [Server-side JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript)

Answer (score 2):

Yup, there are several interpreters:

[Server-Side Javascript uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript) on Wikipedia

Don't know which one/s are the most popular, available, and stable, though.

Answer (score 1):

One popular implementation: http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://commonjs.org/

-- MV

Answer (score 0):

Try [TeaJS](https://code.google.com/p/teajs/), which has a native module for apache - like many solutions it is based on Google's V8 engine but includes most support for the [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Implementations) standard.